# OneSignal Ionic 4 app_id not found

Tags: push-notification, ionic4, onesignal

I am setting up push notifications with onesignal and firebase for my ionic app.

i have done everything correctly, but the device does not show up at onesignal.

when i run the app, i see in the logs:

```
2020-04-11 12:23:46.106 3541-3541/com.decouikit.news I/OneSignal: Location permissions not added on AndroidManifest file
2020-04-11 12:23:46.358 3541-4383/com.decouikit.news I/OneSignal: Device registered, push token = e3Gv3m0dEIM:APA....
2020-04-11 12:23:51.553 3541-4393/com.decouikit.news W/OneSignal: OneSignalRestClient: POST RECEIVED JSON: {"errors":["app_id not found. You may be missing a Content-Type: application/json header."]}
2020-04-11 12:23:51.562 3541-4394/com.decouikit.news W/OneSignal: Failed last request. statusCode: 400
    response: {"errors":["app_id not found. You may be missing a Content-Type: application/json header."]}
2020-04-11 12:24:06.720 3541-4475/com.decouikit.news W/OneSignal: OneSignalRestClient: POST RECEIVED JSON: {"errors":["app_id not found. You may be missing a Content-Type: application/json header."]}
2020-04-11 12:24:06.722 3541-4476/com.decouikit.news W/OneSignal: Failed last request. statusCode: 400
    response: {"errors":["app_id not found. You may be missing a Content-Type: application/json header."]}
2020-04-11 12:24:36.901 3541-4922/com.decouikit.news W/OneSignal: OneSignalRestClient: POST RECEIVED JSON: {"errors":["app_id not found. You may be missing a Content-Type: application/json header."]}
2020-04-11 12:24:36.903 3541-4923/com.decouikit.news W/OneSignal: Failed last request. statusCode: 400
    response: {"errors":["app_id not found. You may be missing a Content-Type: application/json header."]}
2020-04-11 12:25:22.069 3541-4961/com.decouikit.news W/OneSignal: OneSignalRestClient: POST RECEIVED JSON: {"errors":["app_id not found. You may be missing a Content-Type: application/json header."]}
2020-04-11 12:25:22.071 3541-4962/com.decouikit.news W/OneSignal: Failed last request. statusCode: 400
    response: {"errors":["app_id not found. You may be missing a Content-Type: application/json header."]}
...
```

app.component.ts:

```
constructor(
 private oneSignal: OneSignal,
 public platform: Platform,
 public bookmark: BookmarkService,
 public statusBar: StatusBar, public splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
 this.initializeApp();
 this.pages = [
   ...
 ];
}

initializeApp() {
    let self = this;
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
    this.statusBar.styleDefault();
    this.statusBar.overlaysWebView(true);
    this.splashScreen.hide();

    window["plugins"].OneSignal.setLogLevel({logLevel: 4, visualLevel: 4});
    var notificationOpenedCallback = function (jsonData) {
        console.log('notificationOpenedCallback: ' + JSON.stringify(jsonData));
    };

    window["plugins"].OneSignal
        .startInit("ec1c1xxx-3b89-xxxx-8416-xxxxxxa9e85", "304xxxxx11")
        .handleNotificationOpened(notificationOpenedCallback)
        .endInit();
    self.defaultLoad();
});
```

}

Comment: Where is the code mate? Just add it , since if you set every thing correctly no error will apear... so if you please can provide the app.component.ts code so it will be clear to see if there is something wrong...

Comment: i have added the code

Comment: I don't know the implementation in this way, but the errornthat app_id not found that means the startInit not receaving its variables as possible , try to use normal way which is , this.oneSignal.Start... the code is mentioned here https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/onesignal , so try to use the normal way instead of window....

Comment: i have already tried that too

Comment: also im running app on real device and not emulator

Comment: i've now made some searches on such cordova problem, its not much appearing, but what i saw from a user comment was that its a problem with ionic 5 although i don't think like him... as from 3 months or more i was working a project with ionic and onesignal integration, and gradle gave me some warnings on build but though every thing was okay so if gradle makes peoblem build will not occur, if you can remove onesignal cordova plugin and the npm of onesignal then reinstall them both and try, many people may have glitches from onesignal witbout no reasons and would be solved when they do that...

Comment: Are you sure you're using the Google Project ID and not the Firebase Project Id?    They are different.   You can log into google console to get the right ID.